# How to get price value from Amazon production Advertising API in php

Tags: php, xml, amazon-web-services

First time I'm using Amazon Product Advertising API to retrieve production price information, I got the response as below,

```
["Item"]=>
object(stdClass)#15 (3) {
  ["ASIN"]=>
  string(10) "B0017TZY5Y"
  ["OfferSummary"]=>
  object(stdClass)#16 (6) {
    ["LowestUsedPrice"]=>
    object(stdClass)#17 (3) {
      ["Amount"]=>
      int(820)
      ["CurrencyCode"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["FormattedPrice"]=>
      string(8) "EUR 8,20"
    }
    ["LowestCollectiblePrice"]=>
    object(stdClass)#18 (3) {
      ["Amount"]=>
      int(3490)
      ["CurrencyCode"]=>
      string(3) "EUR"
      ["FormattedPrice"]=>
      string(9) "EUR 34,90"
    }
    ["TotalNew"]=>
    string(1) "0"
    ["TotalUsed"]=>
    string(1) "6"
    ["TotalCollectible"]=>
    string(1) "1"
    ["TotalRefurbished"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
  ["Offers"]=>
  object(stdClass)#19 (3) {
    ["TotalOffers"]=>
    int(0)
    ["TotalOfferPages"]=>
    int(0)
    ["MoreOffersUrl"]=>
    string(1) "0"
  }
}
```

I would like to know, how I can retrieve the  `LowestUsedPrice` and `LowestCollectiblePrice`value from the response by using php.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$YourObject->Item->OfferSummary->LowestCollectiblePrice // for LowestCollectiblePrice value 
$YourObject->Item->OfferSummary->LowestUsedPrice // for LowestUsedPrice value
```

Comment: Thanks, That works, but how I can retrieve the amount alone from the value string(8) "EUR 8,20"

Comment: ==> $YourObject->Item->OfferSummary->LowestCollectiblePrice->Amount